# Can not create nested loops in PHP using MySql

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, nested

Hi and thank you for your time,

I am having problems with the following code:

```php
<?php

include './include/config.php';


$sqla = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM sector");
        while ($rowa = $sqla->fetch_assoc()) {
          
        $codigo = $rowa['codigo'];
        $sector = $rowa['sector'];
          echo $sector. "<br>";
    
    $sqlb = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cfamilia WHERE sector = '$codigo'");
            while ($rowb = $sqlb->fetch_assoc()) {

            $cfamilia= $rowb['cfamilia'];
              echo $cfamilia. " - ";
    }
}
?>
```

When I run the code, it only echo´s the first result of the first loop and then seems to get stuck on the inner loop, what am I doing wrong? All data in the database is available and correct.

I am probably doing it the wrong way, but I am no way a programmer.

Thanks for your help

I have searched to check if all data is correct and that all variables were clean.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong _with the code in your question_ that could explain the phenomenon that you report. It could be optimized, for instance by using a MySQL `JOIN`, but that's not relevant to your question.

Comment: Did you check the PHP error logs? Or enable visible error reporting.

Comment: It is quite possible that, for instance, `$sqlb` becomes `NULL` because the data doesn't exist, and this will generate an PHP error.

Comment: yes, this is the error: [Sun Oct 30 16:01:03.311530 2022] [php7:error] [pid 379105]  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in /var/www/html/test.php:15\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/test.php on line 15

Comment: OK, that means that `$sqlb` contains `false`, not a result object. In other words something went wrong with the inner query.

Comment: I do not understand how sqlb can become NULL.

Comment: Yeah, forget about the `NULL`, since it clearly is a boolean `false`. It could be something as the table name: `cfamilia` might really be `familia`. But we don't know what is in your database.

Comment: FIxed, thank you so much, I was nameing a cell name instead of the table name, stupidity on my behalf. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice. Now you know how to check for these errors yourself. 